# Nested reference problem

Tags: game-maker

I have an array of objects tied to a global array in GMS2 
When I try to reference the variable used to position the object I get errors saying the variable hasn't been declared. 
The error also says the object and variable that cause the error are unknown. 
I feel like I'm using the nested reference to point to the current target of the for loop incorrectly.

```
//Place is a local variable used as a index for the array
 Global.hand[place] = noone;
 //The array global.hand is elsewhere set as a 1d array that's 8 items tall
 For(i = place + 1; i < 8; i++)
 {
     Global.hand[i] = global.hand[i + 1];
     Global.hand[i].place -= 1;
 }
 Place = instance_count(card);
```

The snippet is supposed to take an item in the array and move it to the end

The line that's causing the error is Global.hand[i].place -= 1;

Comment: What line gives the error? Please format your code better, it's easier for people to read then. I'll do the edit. :)

Comment: Sorry I tried abstracting the code to make it easier to understand but it required more explanation than the actual function of moving a card from the middle of a hand to the end. The line causing the error is "Global.hand[i].place -= 1;" and the error claims the variable hasn't been declared before being referenced but the same variable is used 4 lines prior making me assume it's how I'm referencing it that's the cause

Comment: When posting stuff, include the *real* code otherwise we might not see the issue if it's a typo or something. Now you have a case issue. `Place` is not the same as `place`. And I don't see a previous use of `hand.place`.

Comment: Never write `Global.hand[i].place`, write `(global.hand[i]).place` instead, because first case may work wrong.

Comment: (global.hand[I]).place gives the same error

Comment: Yes, because it wasn't a solution. Just an important remark.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `hand` object have a member called `place`? I doubt it. `place` looks like a local variable. This is where the error is coming from.

Comment: The global hand[n] is an array pointing to instances of an object that has the local variable place

Comment: Are you sure. The error you're getting indicates otherwise.

Comment: Commenting out that line leaves me with no error

Comment: Right. So I'm betting that `hand.place` is not a legal reference.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" this by adding a global variable that gives me something I can reference later

In the left pressed trigger

```
    global.bookmark = place;

    global.hand[place] = noone;
    for (i = place + 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        global.hand[i] = global.hand[i + 1];
    }
    //place=instance_number(basic_card);
    shuffling = 1;
}
```

In the end step

```
if place > global.bookmark && place != instance_number(basic_card) && shuffling = 1
{
    place -=1;
    shuffling = 0;
}
```

It's not perfect but I don't get crashes anymore

Comment: So you're not referring to `global.hand.place` anymore, as I stated was the problem before.

Comment: Correct, there doesn't appear to be a way to parse that data directly with the structure I'm using